# Stop auto-play video

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, video

I am playing a video with in iframe. which is in auto play mode. I want to make it play on click.

Can I get any help in this?

```
<iframe width="896" height="424" src="http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid1956333307001?bckey=AQ~~,AAABxzD3Y9k~,w_VmDmf4kc-gzMlyacBFjrfIduWxlrSQ&amp;bctid=4235240679001" id="video"></iframe>
```

Comment: Googling "brightcove autoplay" results in http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/player-configuration-parameters as the first result, and the `autoStart` parameter appears to be what you want.

Comment: If it's an iframe to a page you control, then simply change the source code of that page. If it isn't, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<iframe src="http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid1956333307001?bckey=AQ~~,AAABxzD3Y9k~,w_VmDmf4kc-gzMlyacBFjrfIduWxlrSQ&amp;bctid=4235240679001&autoStart=false&width=896&height=424" id="video"></iframe>
```

referenced from [here](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/solutions/embedding-video-cloud-players-iframes)

Comment: `<iframe>` has no `autostart` parameter. It should be in the URL's query string.

Comment: WOW..! That works thanks. Also Can you guide me how can I expand the width and height of the video?

Comment: @ceejayoz I was in the process of updating the answer :/